# Equalize bootstrap pagination height with input+button height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

[image: pagination height]

I have expanded the pagination (Bootstrap-styled) with a "jump-to-page" option but have been struggling to get the paginator list height to match that of the input and the submit button. Can't remember everything I've tried so far but here's the latest code, which is closest to what I want. Still, list height is 29px, input height (`.input-sm`) is 30px, and the button height (`btn-sm`) is 32px.

HTML code:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?&page=Batch">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pn=251&perpage=50&page=Batch">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pn=245&perpage=50&page=Batch">245</a></li>
    ....
    <li><a href="?pn=253&perpage=50&page=Batch">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pn=1693&perpage=50&page=Batch">Last</a></li>
    <form method="get" class="form-horizontal" action="">
        <div class="form-group input-group col-md-2">
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="Batch" />
            <input type="hidden" name="perpage" value="50" />
            <input required type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="pn" size="4" placeholder="Page #">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">Go!</button></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</ul>
```

The extra CSS (the same as the bootstrap, only applied to `input` and `button`):

```
.pagination input,
.pagination button {
    margin-left: -1px;
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsd2zd6c/

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED.**
Culprit was some CSS styling that came before in my custom-styles file.
I had body {font: 11px/16px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} and then a {font-size:11px;} above the pagination code in my custom-styles file. Removed them and the list items and input/button height is now equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the size classes (`input-sm`, `btn-sm`) from both you input and button your padding setting kicks in and does the job.

```
 <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="pn" size="4" placeholder="Page #">
 <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button></span>
```

Here's an updated JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7tq5nzd/

Comment: No, it doesn't, sorry. Look at the fiddle – it's exactly the same as mine. I've tried that.
The only thing removing the `input-sm` and `btn-sm` classes does is equalize the input and button height (at 34px) but they are now much bigger than the pagination (29px).

Comment: This is really odd: I just updated the fiddle you suggested by removing the two classes and now the pagination and input and button are the same height.
I have exactly the same code (html + css) and I've cleared the cache but I can't get the same result. Same as your fiddle.

Comment: I found the problem. It was in some other CSS that interfered.
I had `body {font: 11px/16px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}` and then `a {font-size:11px;}` above the pagination code in my custom-styles file. Removed them and the list items and input/button height is now equal.